# OPC Missing data change

Tags: opc

I'm registering a group of variablse to an OPC DA Server. If someone modifies the items on the server (example: disable one item and enable it after some minutes), I cannot receive any update even when the tag is newly enabled. I tested it also on a Kepware Server doing this:

1. Define a tag as "const variable"
2. Connect to the server and register to the tag
3. Change the function to "random generation" (the server will not disconnect the client)
4. The client will not receive any value 
   but
5. Disconnect the client
6. Reconnect the client
   -> You will obtain random values

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? Is not an accademic question: in real life someone make maintenance to a part of a plant without closing the server: when he puts the full plant online, my client is not receiving any changes.

I suppose that some type of changes results in a new OPC handle and if I'm registred to the old one, I will never receive any value change. Is there a common way to workaround this? I have to monitor some event? 
Anyone had this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This behavior may be specific to OPC tags that reside inside Kepware OPC Server. If you use a real device driver and actually connect it to the equipment, the results may differ.

Comment: No: I have the same problem with wind turbines OPC Server of 2 different vendors and with a simulation OPC Server: I suppose is an OPC issue or something similar. Those vendors sell also an OPC client, that behaves in the same way.

Comment: Do you try to change a tag property on a running opc server with connected clients? Maybe your opc server not support this...

Comment: If I change a value, each client receives the change. If I change something related to the tag itself (example: enable/disable ), only the client connected AFTER the change will receive the new values.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask Kepware. And, is "something related to the tag itself", an OPC tag in itself again? If it is, they should all behave the same in this manner, and if they don't, it's up to the OPC server vendor to explain.

Comment: I have tested 4 different OPC Server, and all behave in the same way. It's like you register a TAG by name, but really the OPC Sever registers an handle : if you disable and re-enable tag, the OPC Server registers a new handle without invalidating the old one.